# Relation chanage not getting reflected in entity model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Am very new to Entity Framework. I am using vs 2012 professional 2012 for building my mvc4 app.

I will try to explain problem in my limited knowledge

I have created Ado.net entity data model. After that I have chnaged db for setting relations. After "`update model from database`" the relations are not gettng added to model classes. So when I run my app errors like

> The relationship 'x.FK_Privileges_Module' was not loaded because the type 'x.Privilege' is not available.

is shown

How can I solve this. I even tried adding manually the relation to corresponding . cs file and still getting error for every newly added relation.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove entities from model designer (Press Yes when message box will ask) and then add entities again.

Note: To delete, select entities and press delete key

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean I have to remove .edmx file and again create

Comment: No you have to remove entities from edmx designer.

Comment: As i said am very new, Can you give me a link describing the same.

Comment: Thx very much. So I have to delete and add entity again  whenevar i add a new relation ? Refreshing won't affect the chnages?

Comment: Update should be working when new things (relation, column) are added. But if you are changing existing things, you have to re add entity.

Comment: One more doubt why the change is not getting reflected in .cs file

Comment: You have to save designer changes.

Answer (score 0):

The edmx is not able to find a Primary Key on Privilege and therefore the foregin key is not valid.

**Add  a Primary Key on Privilege**

Comment: The relations is showing in .edms diagram. But the corr. model class is not showing the relation

Comment: try to remove both tables and re-add and save and then rebuild, even reopening the studio will also helps in some cases.